# $\beta _i = \sigma(\bigcup_{t \in T_i} \mathcal A_t)$, then $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are also independent.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal A, P)$ be a probability space. Let $(\mathcal A_t)_T \subset \mathcal A$ be a family of independent $\sigma$-algebras.

Let $T = T_1 \cup \cdots\cup T_n$ be a disjoint union of nonempty sets.

For each $i$, $\beta _i = \sigma(\bigcup_{t \in T_i} \mathcal A_t)$, then $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_n$ are also independent.

Proof: Let $\mathcal C_i = \{ \bigcap_{t \in F} A_t \mid A_t \in \mathcal A_t, F\in T_i \text{ is finite}\} $.

I have checked that $\mathcal C_i$ is a $\pi$-system. If I can prove $\sigma(\mathcal C_i) = \beta_i$ we are done, as i have the following resut:

[image]

I am stuck here. Need Some Hints to do the problem.

Comment: @michael Hardy  it is a named theorem or some result?

Comment: Your definition of $\mathcal C_i$ does not involve nay probabilites. How can you prove independence by just showing that $\sigma (\mathcal C_i)=\beta _i$?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I Have edited the question you can see now.